# Checkbox disable not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to disable a checkbox in the checkbox list using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). But it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code. The checkbox list has a total of 12 checkboxes.

```
<script src="../AutoComplete Jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var disable = 5;
var i=0;
$(":checkbox").each(function()
                {
                    if(i<disable)
                    {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        i=i+1;
                    }
                });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(':checkbox:lt(5)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

OR

```
$(':checkbox:lt(5)').prop('disabled', true);
```

According to your approach:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(i, check) {
    if (i < disable) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Within the **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** callback function first parameter is the `index` of checkbox. So you don't need to keep `i` for indexing.

To enable the `checkbox` again:

`.removeAttr('disabled');` or `.prop('disabled', false)`.

Comment: @Prince check the last answer.. may be it'll help you

Comment: thanks dude...it's working fine now. n how can i enable the checkbox

Comment: Best way to present gratitude is to accept the answer @Prince.